# How to test if every column is significantly different than the others

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have `data.frame` in R containing hundreds of columns. I need to check if every column is significantly different from all other columns. I was looking at `aov()` function, but I don't know how I should specify the model and how to do it for every column in efficient way. If anyone would have any idea, it'd be nice.

Comment: Change your data from "wide" to "long" format (probably using melt) to get 2 columns, 1 that is the name of each column and the second that is your data to test. Then do pairwise.t.test or pairwise.prop.test with g = your column name variable.

Comment: Thank You for proposal, it could be the way, but then I would have to do this operation repeatedly for every column... And I'm not sure if hundreds of paired t.tests on one data set would be statistically correct...

Comment: Do you mean that you want to compare the means of all pairs of columns, e.g. with a t-test?

Comment: May this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745379/how-can-i-perform-a-pairwise-t-test-in-r-across-multiple-independent-vectors

Comment: Thank You, KFB, it looks good. It just doesn't tell me which column is significantly different from rest of the dataset. ARobertson's hint would do this and I think combination of Your link and his advice could work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for advice with statistical methodology. However, the question is not of sufficient quality to migrate it to stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pairwise.t.test`, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18447511/489704), we can identify rows of the *p* table for which all comparisons have `p <= 0.05`.

For example:

```
# dummy data
set.seed(1)
J <- 10 # number of groups
n <- 50 # number of obs per group
m <- mapply(rnorm, n, rnorm(J))
d <- data.frame(y=c(m), x=factor(rep(seq_len(ncol(m)), each=nrow(m))))

plot(jitter(as.numeric(d$x)), d$y, pch=20, xlab='Group', ylab='Value')
```

[image]

```
p <- cbind(rbind('1'=NA, pairwise.t.test(d$y, d$x)$p.value), NA)
p[upper.tri(p)] <- t(p)[upper.tri(t(p))] # add values to upper triangle
rowSums(p <= 0.05, na.rm=TRUE) == J - 1

#     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Elements of the final vector are `TRUE` if all other groups have significantly (at alpha = 0.05) different means. The default p-adjustment method for `pairwise.t.test` is `holm` - see `p.adjust.methods` for available methods.