# Extracting values over loop of t-tests

Tags: r

I am attempting to iterate over ~60 columns with the goal to perform a t-test weighted by case/control status, and to capture the output as a list. Here is my attempt so far -- note that my data frame is called biomarkers, and columns 3-59 represent my variable of interest, to be weighted by column 2 (called case):

```
tests <- list()
column_biomarkers <- colnames(biomarkers[3:59])

for (i in column_biomarkers){
  tests[[i]] <-  t.test(biomarkers$i[case == 1],biomarkers$i[case == 0],pool.sd=FALSE,na.rm=TRUE)
  }

sapply(tests, function(x) {
  c(x$estimate[1],
    x$estimate[2],
    ci.lower = x$conf.int[1],
    ci.upper = x$conf.int[2],
    p.value = x$p.value)
})
```

However, I this attempt results in the following error:

> Error in var(x) : 'x' is NULL

Any advice would be much appreciated! I am new to using R.

Sample data:

```
structure(list(subject = 1:10, case = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), biomarker_1 = c(308.29999, 2533.3, 2723.3, 3125.3, 
853, 6442.2998, 1472.5, 170.5, 64.5, 2624.8), biomarker_2 = c(4930.7998, 
2401, 5158.5, 6526, 3774.2, 5753, 1955.2, 1332.2, 1296.8, 5859.2998
), biomarker_3 = c(4810, 3279.5, 7929.5, 8353, 4074.2, 7940.5, 
1545.7, 2189.2, 1488.7, 6352.5)), .Names = c("subject", "case", 
"biomarker_1", "biomarker_2", "biomarker_3"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Not sure why you have an error, but all of the `tests[[i]]` should be the same since you don't use `i` in the `t.test()` call

Comment: whoops -- should have been biomarkers$i ... sorry about that, thanks. I edited, above is the code that generates an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I perform a pairwise t.test in R across multiple independent vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745379/how-can-i-perform-a-pairwise-t-test-in-r-across-multiple-independent-vectors)

Comment: You should write it this way: `biomarkers[case == 1,i]`

Comment: Thanks HubertL. If I correct the code as suggested I get the following error: Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: I think you must replace `case` with `biomarkers$case` as well.

Comment: Thanks Kunal -- tried that as well, still get same error as above :(

Comment: Done -- see above for sample data with 3 biomarkers and 10 subjects

Comment: @bdemarest - simply put quotes around the subject values.

Comment: also -- edited so subjects are numerical instead of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another possible solution.

```
tests <- list()
column_biomarkers <- colnames(biomarkers[3:5])
for (i in column_biomarkers){
  tests[[i]] <-t.test(biomarkers[[i]][biomarkers$case == 1],biomarkers[[i]][biomarkers$case == 0],pool.sd=FALSE,na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

R does not like biomarkers$i[biomarkers$case == 1], R is not accepting i as a valid column name thus using the [[ ]] notation seems to work.

Comment: While this may solve the OP's question, the best practices for R is [vectorized code](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html) not iterative programming (i.e., looping over elements of vector/matrix), usually done in lower level languages.

Answer (score 2):

Consider splitting data frame into the two groupings and run t-tests across the columns using [`mapply()`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/mapply) (*the multivariate apply function to run operations element-wise between objects*).

```
controldf <- df[df$case==1, 3:ncol(df)]
treatmentdf <- df[df$case==0, 3:ncol(df)]

tfct <- function(v1, v2){
             t.test(v1, v2, pool.sd=FALSE, na.rm=TRUE)
        }

ttests <- mapply(tfct, controldf, treatmentdf)
ttests

#             biomarker_1               biomarker_2              
# statistic   -0.4310577                2.287416                 
# parameter   7.943542                  7.987304                 
# p.value     0.677885                  0.05152236               
# conf.int    Numeric,2                 Numeric,2                
# estimate    Numeric,2                 Numeric,2                
# null.value  0                         0                        
# alternative "two.sided"               "two.sided"              
# method      "Welch Two Sample t-test" "Welch Two Sample t-test"
# data.name   "v1 and v2"               "v1 and v2"    
#      
#             biomarker_3              
# statistic   1.169058                 
# parameter   7.995322                 
# p.value     0.2760513                
# conf.int    Numeric,2                
# estimate    Numeric,2                
# null.value  0                        
# alternative "two.sided"              
# method      "Welch Two Sample t-test"
# data.name   "v1 and v2"
```

Even migrate results to a data frame:

```
# Transposed data frame output of results
testdf <- data.frame(t(ttests))
head(testdf)

#              statistic parameter    p.value              conf.int
# biomarker_1 -0.4310577  7.943542   0.677885   -3219.767, 2206.667
# biomarker_2   2.287416  7.987304 0.05152236 -19.24659, 4598.82973
# biomarker_3   1.169058  7.995322  0.2760513   -1785.201, 5455.684
#                       estimate null.value alternative
# biomarker_1   1727.85, 2234.40          0   two.sided
# biomarker_2 5272.575, 2982.783          0   two.sided
# biomarker_3 5897.425, 4062.183          0   two.sided
#                              method data.name
# biomarker_1 Welch Two Sample t-test v1 and v2
# biomarker_2 Welch Two Sample t-test v1 and v2
# biomarker_3 Welch Two Sample t-test v1 and v2
```

Comment: Thanks! this makes a lot of sense. Applying this to my own data, however, I get the following error: Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: Do not include the subject or case columns in the split dataframes. Notice the subset of columns `3: ncol(df)`.