# t.test for all combinations of a grouping factor first by subsetting

Tags: r

I am trying to do a t.test for all combinations of my grouping factors, first by only choosing and subsetting the data based on a selection criteria from another column.

the structure of my data:
str(mydata)

```
'data.frame':   240 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Group   : chr  "G1" "G1" "G1" "G1" ...
 $ Category: chr  "Cat1" "Cat1" "Cat1" "Cat1" ...
 $ Subgroup: chr  "SG1" "SG1" "SG1" "SG1" ...
 $ Score   : num  0.156 0.131 0.092 0.319 0.179 ...
 $ SD      : num  0.0768 0.0768 0.0768 0.0768 0.0768 ...
 $ SE      : num  0.0172 0.0172 0.0172 0.0172 0.0172 ...
```

I have three groups in the the `Group` column: **G1**, **G2** and **G3** 
I have four categories in the `Category` column: **Cat1**, **Cat2**, **Cat3** and **Cat4**
I have twelve subgroups: **SG1**, **SG2**, until **SG12**

Currently, I am creating a list of all combinations for the Subgroup names first by subsetting the data based of their group id, so in this example G1 and G3:

```
combinations <- combn(unique(mydata[mydata$Group %in% c("G1", "G3"),]$Subgroup),2, simplify = FALSE)
```

then doing a t.test for each of these combinations, [referring to the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14746297/4230650):

```
results <- lapply(seq_along(combinations), function (n) {
  mydatatemp <- mydata[rownames(mydata$Subgroup) %in% unlist(combinations[n]),]
  result <- t.test(mydatatemp[,1], mydatatemp[,2], alternative="two.sided", var.equal=TRUE)
  return(result)})
results
```

the error i get is the following:

```
Error in t.test.default(mydatatemp[, 1], mydatatemp[, 2], alternative = "two.sided",  : 
  not enough 'x' observations In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

**Is there a more efficient way to do this? Otherwise, how to correct this error?**

### update

actually the problem is how to call the values in the `Score` column in the t.test formula?

Comment: @coffeinjunky no, the groups are of the same size, exactly the same.

Comment: @coffeinjunky yeah, i don't think it is the problem. The problem comes from the formula, there is something wrong in it, that i can't find it.

Comment: @coffeinjunky i tried it using another software, the t test works for this same data. but i want to do it in R

Comment: @coffeinjunky i don't get what you mean, can you post your comment in an answer and provide an example code? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should look like this:

```
results <- lapply(seq_along(combinations), function (n) {
  mydatatemp <- mydata[with(mydata, Subgroup %in% unlist(combinations2[n]) & Group %in% c("G1", "G3")),]
  result <- t.test(mydatatemp[
                   mydatatemp$Subgroup == sapply(combinations[n], "[",1),4],
                   mydatatemp[mydatatemp$Subgroup == sapply(combinations[n], "[", 2),4],
                   alternative="two.sided", var.equal=TRUE)
             return(result)})
results
```

Answer (score 2):

To address the discussion in the comments: If the problem is in one of the subgroups, then the following may help to identify which one it is:

First, let's recreate the error:

```
smalln <- data.frame(a=1, b=2)
t.test(smalln$a, smalln$b)
> Error in t.test.default(smalln$a, smalln$b) : not enough 'x' observations
```

Ok, we can recreate the error. Now, let's capture it before it disrupts other calls (such as your `sapply` call that executes it):

```
failproof.t <- failwith(default="I need coffee", t.test, quiet = T)
failproof.t(smalln$a, smalln$b)
[1] "I need coffee"
```

If you use `failproof.t` in your call to `sapply`, `sapply` will carry out all tests until the end. Normally, when an error is generated, your code will stop. With this method, it still continues to work and will spit out a pre-defined default value instead of the error message. With this approach, you will be able to look at your `results` list to see for which group combinations the error occurred.